# hook keypress и изменение нажатия

Tags: c++, hook

Интересует вопрос, реально ли через hook словить нажатие определенной кнопки и заменить на нажатие совершенно другой. Например на ноутбуке нету numpad клавиатуры и надо при нажатии, допустим, F1 симулировалось нажатие клавиши numpad 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Легко. Установите хук на `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

HHOOK hook;

LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *p = reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *>(lParam);
    DWORD newVkCode;
    INPUT inputs[1];
    UINT ret;

    char wParamStr[16];
    char vkStr[16] = "";

    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        strcpy(wParamStr, "KEYDOWN");
    else if (wParam == WM_KEYUP)
        strcpy(wParamStr, "KEYUP");
    else if (wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
        strcpy(wParamStr, "SYSKEYDOWN");
    else if (wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP)
        strcpy(wParamStr, "SYSKEYUP");
    else
        strcpy(wParamStr, "UNKNOWN");

    if (p->vkCode == 10)
        strcpy(vkStr, "<LF>");
    else if (p->vkCode == 13)
        strcpy(vkStr, "<CR>");
    else
        vkStr[0] = p->vkCode;

    printf("%d - %s - %lu (%s) - %d - %lu\n",
        nCode, wParamStr, p->vkCode, vkStr, p->scanCode, p->time);

    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wScan = 0;
    inputs[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    inputs[0].ki.time = 0;
    inputs[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    if (wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) {
        inputs[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    }

    if (p->vkCode == VK_F1 && (p->flags & LLKHF_INJECTED) == 0) {
        inputs[0].ki.wVk = VK_NUMPAD1;
        ret = SendInput(1, inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
        return 1;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MSG messages;

    hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboardHook, NULL, 0);
    if (hook == NULL) {
        printf("Error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Waiting for messages ...\n");
    while (GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
    return 0;
}
```